# Maven class not found multiple projects

Tags: maven

New to maven... I have several projects that are interdependent. One of the project "com.xxx.yyy.data" has dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.lookup</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.xxxx.lookup.zzz</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I do not have any issues during build but when I try to deploy it gives error "module failed with the following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: >com.xxxx.lookup.zzz.hhh"

I am using eclipse. I also had another question, where does this com.xxx.lookup.zzz.jar file is stored - in the workspace..or in the .m2/repository.

Comment: It's saved at .m2/repository/com/xxx/lookup/zzz/

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is a *RuntimeException*. Have you checked that the problem is related to maven?

Comment: I looked up at .m2/repository/com/xxx/lookup/zzz....The .m2/repository/com/xxx/lookup/zzz/..build-snapshot.jar.last.updated. the below is what it shows in the file #Fri Feb 27 11:20:51 CST 2015 http\://nexus.test.xxx.com/nexus/content/groups/public/.lastUpdated=1425057651341. but this project is in my local workpace..not in nexus...so how do i point to my local instead of http\://nexus.test.xxxxx.com/nexus/content/groups/public/.error=

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the missing class in the class path of your application at runtime. This error is very likely not to be caused by Maven, but by a faulty class path setup. If you are using Eclipse, you can set up your class path in the project settings.